# Error 2032 in Chrome using pepflashplayer.dll

Tags: apache-flex, iis-7, flash

I have a flex application that worked just swell until chrome got a new player: 21.0.1180.83\PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll

The application must break when it loads parameters from the xml file. It hangs displaying the loader of the application and on the bottom is the "Error #2032" msg.

Application still works on my localhost and in onther browser but not on the production server (IIS7). This unfortunately also means its a bit harder to debug...

Some suspicions of what might be wrong:

- If I disable the pepflashplayer it works again in chrome (on the old player) so I am confident its related to the player.
- Could it be related to a crossdomain file? I only have the crosdomain.xml file on the subdomain (where the parameters.xml resides)
- Could it be related to mimo type set in IIS for the xml
- I also connect to web services. Additionally its a problem as it is http to https call. Could this be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I solved it. The problem was in an old .actionscriptproperties autogenerated file that included a lot of obsolete references to various crossdomain.xml.

Seems this do not get cleaned on project clean, so a fresh import of the project was needed which fixed the #2032 error.

Hope this helps someone.